# Shortcode appears at the top of page

Tags: javascript, wordpress, shortcode

I have created a shortcode which is just meant to simply return some text, and I put it in the functions.php file, but this just displays the text of the shortcode at the top of the homepage of my website. This is also my first custom shortcode so I would not be surprised if there are mistakes in it. I have checked answers to similar questions but none of them have helped. The code is:

```
function short_description_subtitle_shortcode( $atts ) {
$a = shortcode_atts( array(
      'subtitle' => '<h4>Classes 1 to 14</h4><p></p>'
   ), $atts );
   return $a['<h4>subtitle</h4><p></p>'];
}

add_shortcode( 'short_description_subtitle', 'short_description_subtitle_shortcode' );
```

How can I correct this?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
function short_description_subtitle_shortcode( $atts ) {

  return "<h4>Classes 1 to 14</h4><p>" . $atts['val'] . "</p>";


  add_shortcode( 'short_description_subtitle',  'short_description_subtitle_shortcode' 
);
```

Then your shortcode will = [short_description_subtitle val = "2"]

Comment: My shortcode will need to be editable, e.g. if I put [short_description_subtitle subtitle="Hello world"], it would display "Hello world" in that format

Comment: The "Classes 1 to 14" is a bit redundant really, all I need is formatted text using the shortcode that I can edit

Comment: `return "<h4>" . $atts['val'] . "</h4>";`

Just return your variable in whatever format you want. In this case the variable is between h4 tags

Comment: Then your shortcode will = [short_description_subtitle val = "YOUR TEXT TO DISPLAY"]

Comment: I used this exact code but it still appears at the top of every page above the page contents

Comment: It has to go into the content editor of the page

If it already is there then show me the php template of the page as there is an error in the php template otherwise.